# In Android Expanded List, how do I get the current view when group is expanded?

Tags: android, android-view

So I have an Expanded List:

```
ExpandableListView expListView;
```

I setup a group expand listner, which I plan to change some image inside the group view based on group expanded status.

```
    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (curExpandedGeoArea >= 0 && groupPosition != curExpandedGeoArea) {
                expListView.collapseGroup(curExpandedGeoArea);
                // How do I get the view of the current expanded view?
            }
            curExpandedGeoArea = groupPosition;
        }
    });
```

My question is, in the onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) function, how do I get the View of the expanded group?

I read other questions, and it is suggested I use the

```
onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)
```

function, which contain View v, the problem with that approach is that I might expand my group programmatically, so that function is not called, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in [getGroupView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupView%28int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method of ExpandableListAdapter. You can check whether current group is expanding or not using isExpanded parameter of getGropuView and change whatever icon you want to change.

Comment: Yup, worked really well, I didn't know that getGetView can be used in that situation, I just thought it was called when View is init.